# find closest distance between a polygons segment and a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, oracle-dbms

[image]

I have a building with a house number as a point feature which is the centroid of that polygon.  I want to locate the closest segment of the building to a street like in the picture and remove the house number point on that segment.

How can i handle this?

I read about :
Near_analysis (in_features, near_features, {search_radius}, {location}, {angle})

But in this case the segment of a polygon is the parameter not the polygon at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can explode the Building Outlines to individual segments by running "Split Line At Vertices". I would create a Centroid for each Segment, "Feature to Point" tool, and then run "Near" on the Segment Centroids and Street Lines to locate the closest Segment of each Building Outline. You can test the different tools to see what works the best for your project, you may not need Segment Centroids.

Comment: How can i automatize this, for any house-number i select ?

Comment: Most all the ArcGIS tools will process a Selected Set, this is default behavior. You shouldn't need to add any logic if you only want a single Address processed. You might add a "Select By Attribute" query when inputing a single Street Address as a text string.